# ¿Por que mi estado queda en Null en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Estoy aprendiendo React, sin embargo tengo una duda, Estoy manejando un estado que guarde una IP para luego pasarle dicha Ip a una API y me traiga la hora actual basada en la ip publica del usuario.

Sin embargo el hacer la peticion en el useEffect mi variable entra a la petiicion de la API como null

```
const [ip, setIp] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    
    const getIP = async () => {
        try {
            const results = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
            const data = await results.json();
            const dataIp = data.ip;
            setIp(dataIp);
        }
        catch{
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    getIP()
    setTimeout(() => {
        const getLocalDate = async () =>{
            try{
                const results =  await fetch(`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip/${ip}`)
                const data = await results.json()
                const localDate = new Date(data.datetime.split('.')[0])
                setHour(localDate)
                setLoading(false)
            }
            catch{
                setLoading(false)
                setError(true)
            }
        }
        getLocalDate()
    },3000)
}, []);
```

Comment: Revisaste las dependencias del useEffect?, Podrias poner el codigo completo para ver la declaracion de UseState, que tipo de dato es dataIP?

Comment: Lo tengo como null, pero segun entiendo el useEffect se ejecuta antes del render, por lo cual deberia cambiar la IP no ?

Comment: EL UseEffect en algunos casos lleva dependencias en el `[]`, si le pones un console log a dataIp que valor te muestra? Si es un string deberias inicializar el useState con `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el estado en react es asíncrono y la única forma de saber que el estado ha cambiado es pasándole dicho estado como dependencia a un useEffect.

En tu caso, tu useEffect sólo se está ejecutando en el primer render, por lo que el estado "ip" siempre será nulo. Deberías separar las dos request en diferentes useEffect y agregar la ip como dependencia, de la siguiente manera:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getIP();
  }, []); // En el primer render haces la request para recuperar la ip

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ip) { // con este if te aseguras de hacer la llamada siempre que haya valor
      getLocalDate();
    }
  }, [ip]); // Este useEffect se ejecutará siempre que el estado "ip" cambie
```

Como buenas prácticas, ya que estás empezando, deberías tener en cuenta que un useEffect sólo debería hacer una cosa, que se ponen al principio del archivo y en orden de ejecución. Y que hacer un setTimeout siempre debería ser tu última opción ;)

Comment: Mucho más claro, use el set Time out porque quería réplica el loading, de verdad muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Considera que estas haciendo dos *request* dentro del mismo `useEffect`, por lo cual el valor del *ip* sólo será visible dentro del próximo *render*.

Una forma de solucionarlo sería crear un segundo `useEffect` que observe tu estado iP y se ejecute sólo cuando cambie su valor.

```
useEffect(() => { //... llamada a la API pasandole la IP }, [ ip ])
```

Nos comentas si te funciona :D

Comment: Si me funciona de esta manera no entendía el porque muchas gracias